# Add size() to keySet() after retainAll on one line

Tags: java, listview

I'm experimenting with views. Is there a possibility to write the size() method on the second last line without useing lambdas?? As follows:

```
eintraege.retainAll(Arrays.asList(names)).size(); // Does not work


public static int countNames(Map<String, PhoneNumber> phoneBook,
                             String[] names) {
    Set<String> eintraege = phoneBook.keySet();
    eintraege.retainAll(Arrays.asList(names));  
    return eintraege.size();  // Works fine
}
```

Comment: No. `retainAll` returns a boolean on which you can't call `size()`. You could use  `return stream().filter(..).count()` but I think that is not what you are asking about.

Comment: What's so bad about having this in multiple lines? It's easier to read that way... However, note that your code has (probably unexpected) side effects: `retainAll()` removes any elements not in the list and this would also remove those elements from the map since the key set is backed by the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does not work fine.

`retainAll` will delete all the keys that aren't in `names`. `.keySet()` **does not** return a copy. It returns a different view. **Deleting elements from what `.keySet()` returns deletes them from the original map!**

Thus, this code will give the right answer... and will have corrupted your phonebook as well.

If you must use `retainAll`, you'd have to make a copy. No, there is no way to chain the `size()` call.

But, making a copy is silly here. You really just want to, well, count names. This code does not mangle the original phone book and is far faster:

```
int count = 0;
for (String n : names) if (phoneBook.containsKey(n)) count++;
return count;
```

It also shows the folly of 'worrying about lines'. That code above is 3 lines and is plausibly readable as is. Certainly a ton of folks that do use lambdas would put the exact same 'semantic load' on a single line. But that is not a particularly commonly employed code style. At some point you're more 'measuring the efficacy of your code style' than actually measuring the complexity of your code. You also see extremes that serve no purpose and make code harder to read: A `.stream().map()` etc operation that does 18 different things, all piled on a single huge line, and some clown going: HA! See! shorter!

Keep the characteristics of your data structures in mind. `list.contains(n)` takes time that scales up with how large the list is. `map.containsKey(n)`, or `set.contains(n)`, that takes constant time (or in case of `TreeMap`, that takes time that scales with `log2(n)`, but remember that `log2(1_000_000)` is still only a few tens of loops. log scaling is doable by computers even for humongous inputs.

Hence, the above code is relatively fast, but if you flip it around:

```
for (String n : phoneBook.keySet()) if (names.contains(n)) count++;
```

that would grow to be very slow indeed, especially if `names` is large.

Comment: Thanks..In this exercise I'm not allowed to use loops and I should alter the original code via views...

Comment: @Rubus you could also create a set out of `names`, call `retainAll(keySet)` on this and then get the size. This would not require an explicit loop (although `retainAll()` etc. _will_ use loops internally), remove any duplicate names and _not_ alter your key set (as you're only reading it).

Comment: @Rubus surely a method named `countNames` should _not_ be altering anything at all. If it is, tell your teacher / the publisher of the tutorial they suck at naming.